# How to set object name?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(window.navigator);
```

console result chrome:

```
Navigator {}
```

// name "Navigator"

object:

```
var a = {};
console.log(a) // result Object {}
```

How to set/rename Object name?

Comment: It's extremely unclear as to what you're trying to do?...

Comment: I think you might be confusing a `constructor` with a plain `object`.

Answer (score 7):

You are talking about `OOP` in `javascript`. You need first define a `class` and then create an `instance` as follows:

```
var Person = function(){/* Constructor */};
var pepe = new Person();
console.log(pepe); // result Person{}
```

Comment: As a note, [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Prototype-based_programming) is technically a [prototype-based programing language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Prototype-based_programming) which is a classless model of OOP. Using `class` here is relative as it's simply an object of which an instance is intialized from. It's more applicable in [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)  `class Person { ... }`.

Comment: @War10ck Technically true, but in practice the prototype acts like a class.

Comment: @Barmar You're absolutely right. I wasn't trying to be overly picky just wanted to note that for future reference. If one were to not know this and Google JavaScript classes, they'll come up with [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) first which differs from the answer above since it's ES6 and may cause some confusion.

Comment: if classes act like objects in js, then why can't I create an object and give it a constructor name later?